# React useContext() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code for my context provider, I have my  wrapped in  component but still when I try to use it in a child using either useProductState or useProductDispatch, it returns undefined (throws err);

```
import React from "react";

import productsReducer from "./productsReducer";

const ProductsStateContext = React.createContext();
const ProductsDispatchContext = React.createContext();

const initialState = {
  restaurantTitle: "",
  restaurantId: "VljSa5Eakepw9QkTAUOW",
  productsCollection: "",
  categories: [],
  defaultCategory: "",
  isLoading: true,
};

function ProductsProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(productsReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <ProductsStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <ProductsDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </ProductsDispatchContext.Provider>
    </ProductsStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useProductsState() {
  const context = React.useContext(ProductsStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useProductsState must be used within a ProductsProvider");
  }
  return context;
}
function useProductsDispatch() {
  const context = React.useContext(ProductsDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "useProductsDispatch must be used within a ProductsProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
}

export { ProductsProvider, useProductsState, useProductsDispatch };
```

Can somebody explain how this works, I'm trying to access state and dispatch into a functional component that is a child of .

UPDATE:

I've got this as an action for my reducer

```
case "FETCH_RESTAURANT_DATA": {
      return fetchRestaurantData(state, action.payload);
    }
```

Function body looks like this:

```
const fetchRestaurantData = (state, value) => {
  let newState = state;
  return axios
    .post(api.routes.restaurant, { restaurantId: state.restaurantId })
    .then((res) => {
      newState.restaurantTitle = res.data.restaurantTitle;

      res.data.categories.forEach(
        (category) =>
          (newState.categories[category] = {
            loaded: false,
            props: [],
          })
      );
      newState.defaultCategory = res.data.categories[0];
      newState.productsCollection = res.data.productsCollection;
      newState.isLoading = false;

      return axios.post(api.routes.category, {
        productsCollection: res.data.productsCollection,
        categoryId: newState.defaultCategory,
      });
    })
    .then((res) => {
      newState.categories[newState.defaultCategory].props =
        res.data[newState.defaultCategory];
      newState.categories[newState.defaultCategory].loaded = true;
      console.log(newState);
      return newState;
    });
};
```

What i think is going on, I think in reducer it does not wait for my response and update context state with an undefined value which then triggers my error.

I have tried to make a middle async function that awaits for fetchRestaurantData() response but it is still updating before getting a response

Comment: I see you are exporting your custom hooks but not contexts, I'd add them into export at the bottom. Maybe this is causing the issue

Comment: Well im using an api call in a reducer action and i think my consumer triggers an re-render before the response changes my state and that is why my context returns as undefined, but i dont know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for the response in `fetchRestaurantData`:

```js
const fetchRestaurantData = async (state, value) => {  // add async keyword to the function 
  let newState = state;
  return await axios  // here add await 
    .post(api.routes.restaurant, { restaurantId: state.restaurantId })
    .then((res) => {
      newState.restaurantTitle = res.data.restaurantTitle;

      res.data.categories.forEach(
        (category) =>
          (newState.categories[category] = {
            loaded: false,
            props: [],
          })
      );
      newState.defaultCategory = res.data.categories[0];
      newState.productsCollection = res.data.productsCollection;
      newState.isLoading = false;

      return axios.post(api.routes.category, {
        productsCollection: res.data.productsCollection,
        categoryId: newState.defaultCategory,
      });
    })
    .then((res) => {
      newState.categories[newState.defaultCategory].props =
        res.data[newState.defaultCategory];
      newState.categories[newState.defaultCategory].loaded = true;
      console.log(newState);
      return newState;
    });
};
```

More information about the [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)